Is Apollo Client Devtools compatible with new React Native DevTools?
With the launch of the 0.76 version of React Native there is a new devTools and I was wondering if the Apollo Client Devtools is compatible with it.

Afaik those devtools don't allow for any third party plugins so no, not at the moment.
We are working on integrating the AC devtools with the VSCode extension though, at which point you will be able to use them again with React Native.

I just want to be sure, but for all react native app using Hermes currently, there isn't any working apollo client devtools ?

I believe there's a Flipper plugin, but not a lot more :/
